# Cómo poner una imagen de fondo en un UserControl

Tags: c#

¿Cómo pongo una imagen en un UserControl?

Cuando la pongo con el image, no me muestra la imagen, pero si lo pongo como background en un rectangle, label, grid, me manda este error:

```
Se produjo la excepción System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.
  HResult=0x80131501
  Mensaje = 'Se produjo una excepción al proporcionar un valor en 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension'.' (número de línea: '10'; posición de línea: '14').
  Origen = PresentationFramework
  Seguimiento de la pila:
   en System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   en System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   en System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   en System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   en imagen_fondo.UserControl1.InitializeComponent() en E:\Projects\imagen_fondo\imagen_fondo\UserControl1.xaml: línea 1

Excepción interna 1:
FileNotFoundException: No se pudo encontrar el archivo 'd:\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\imagen_fondo\imagen_fondo\bin\Debug\logo.png'.
```

La imagen que trato de poner se encuentra dentro del proyecto.

Ya intenté ponerlo de esta forma:

- Primera Opción

  ```
  ImageBrush ImageSource ="pack://application:,,,/logo.png"/>
  ```
- Segunda Opción

  ```
  ImageBrush ImageSource="logo.png"
  ```

---

les pondré imagen para explicarme mejor

en la primera imagen muestro como tengo el código en XAML
[image]

en la segunda imagen muestro el error que me sale al ejecutar el codigo o cuando trato de ponerlo en un elementHost
[image]

Comment: probaste hacer que copie el archivo de logo tambien al hacer el deploy?

Comment: Creo que es importante dejar el stack de la excepción, porque muestra un mensaje importante que puede ser clave para responder la pregunta: _No se pudo encontrar el archivo 'd:\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\imagen_fondo\imagen_fondo\bin\Debug\logo.png'_

Comment: @fedorqui lo único que considero que falte es que indique si lo quiere colocar de manera manual o dinámica. por lo que yo noto es manual, pero mejor que nos confirme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo quieres hacer dinamicamente me comentas para que edite la respuesta.

Antes de continuar, elimina la imagen de tu proyecto, despues limpia la solución y luego has un Rebuild. :) (Clic derecho en el proyecto, para visualizar las opciones)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso 1, si tienes una carpeta donde están tus imágenes sáltate este paso, si no la tienes, recomiendo crear una llamada Assets (el nombre que le pongas es opcional).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Agrega la imagen a tu carpeta utilizando las opciones que te da visual studio
   Clic derecho en tu carpeta (Assets)/Add/Existing Item

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.Selecciona tu imagen en el cuadro de dialogo (en este ejemplo mi imagen se llama background).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Una vez que tengas tu imagen en tu proyecto, dirigete a tu user control, y en el Grid principal (o cualquier contenedor que utilices) en su panel de propiedades dirigete al apartado de Brush en la opción Background y presiona el icono de Image, como se muestra en la imagen de abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. En la propiedad Source, selecciona la imagen que se encuentra en tu carpeta Assets.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6.Como extra, en mi ventana principal mando a llamar al UserControl con el que trabajamos en este ejercicio y lo agrego a mi grid principal (el de la ventana principal) con el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

7. Este es el resultado, al ejecutar la aplicación.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, antes que nada gracias por tomarse el tiempo de apoyarme.

lo que quiero es ponerlo manualmente, ya lo hice como lo pusiste en las imágenes y a un así me sigue saliendo mal.

mi pantalla principal es un Form, y a lo que vi en tu ejemplo usas puro wpf tipo windows

Comment: Que interesante tema, te soy sincero nunca se me paso por la mente integrar una pantalla de WPF en un formulario de WinForms, es algo que no he realizado, investigando un poco di con este articulo:

http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/wpf-and-windows-forms-integration.aspx

Voy a realizar la practica y vemos si encontramos la solución. Saludos!!!

Comment: @Daniel duda tu imagen en su propiedad Build Action tiene un valor de Resource?

Comment: gracias, ya solucione el problema, el error estaba en la propiedad del build action, el valor que tenia estaba como page, se soluciono el error poniendo el valor Resource, gracias por su apoyo